# Safer way to heat 1 oz of oil

Tags: oil

I am looking for an alternative to a procedure that my wife uses. She has been doing this for a very long time, and is very resistant to change.

She takes a metal ladle, puts about 1 oz of vegetable oil in it, then holds it on the electric stove burner until the oil bubbles. Then she adds Geera (Cumin) to the oil. This is then added to the stew pot.

One possibility is a very small metal pot, but I haven't found anything suitable. Maybe there is name for something like this that would help me find it.

Comment: If she has been doing it for a 'very long time', and no-one has been injured, and the house hasn't burned down, why are you seeking to intervene? If I tried a similar thing, my wife would very soon put me in my place, and rightly so.

Answer (score 3):

Two other potential vessels are:

- Turkish coffee pots (cezve), though these might be unstable with so little weight in them
- mugs designed to be used on camping stoves. These may be stainless steel, but I have one titanium and one enamelled steel. I use them to boil water when camping.

Honestly though, I'd just use my smallest (15cm/6") saucepan, probably the stainless one rather than the non-stick one.

Answer (score 2):

There are little pans available on the market. For example, I have a very small non sticky pan, fitting the content of a single egg, which I also use when I want to roast a couple of table spoons of puffed wheat for breakfast.

Searching "4 inches pan" returned for example the following pan.

[image]

Same for "6 inches pan".

To make them sit properly on the gas stove, you might want to use this or similar small gas cooker hob stove top reducer

[image]

Comment: When buying tiny pans, look for ones with small, light handles. They're more stable. But on some gas stoves you'll struggle to get them to sit stably at all

Comment: You can often find tiny cast iron pans.  I sometimes see them at thrift stores or antique stores here in the US.  I’m not sure if they’re for melting butter, or a decorative ash tray, or what.  They’re maybe 3 to 4” across (7.5-10cm)

Comment: @Joe I've seen them (and non-stick ones) sold new and labelled for making fried eggs and mini omelettes.  Some are even fancy shapes.  That's in the UK